# Reactive Extensions in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reactive-programming

I am learning to use Rx in winforms. please let me know how to update my progressBar when i use this code.

```
Observable.ToAsync<Boolean>(DoLogin)().ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(
    l => {
        XtraMessageBox.Show(this, "Welcome " + DefaultManager.Principal.Identity.Name, "Loged in successfully", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    },
    ex => { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); },
    () => { }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling [`ObserveOnDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211843%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), which means that when the observable will use the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) that was on the thread when `ObserveOnDispatcher` was called to dispatch the notification to the subscribers.

In this case, it will be the [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx) instance (which can be set up by setting the [static `AutoInstall` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.autoinstall.aspx) to `true`) that is on the thread which will use the message pump to publish to the subscribers.

Basically, you can replace your calls to `XtraMessageBox` with calls to a [`ProgressBar` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) to update when the subscription is notified.